# foreign key query play! framework 2.+ ebean

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm new to play framework and the Ebean ORM.

Basically, I have two models one is a `RegUsers` the other is `RegIds`. In my registration Ids I put a many to one relationship on the Field `RegUsers`. Stating, if I'm not mistaken that one user can have many registration ids.

`RegId` model:

```
@Entity 
public class RegId extends Model{
    public static Finder<Long,RegId> finder = new Finder<Long,RegId>(Long.class, RegId.class);

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    public RegUsers regUsers;

    public String regId;
}
```

`RegUser` model:

```
@Entity 
public class RegUsers extends Model{

    public static Finder<Long,RegUsers> find = new Finder<Long,RegUsers>(Long.class, RegUsers.class);

    @Id
    public Long id;

    public String email;
    public String name;
}
```

A `RegId` must have a `RegUser`, but a `RegUser` does not need to have a `RegId`.
For one of my views I'm trying to show all `RegUsers` who do have an `RegId` only once, but cannot figure out how to do this.

I got close with querying the `RegId` table like so:

```
List<RegId> reg = RegId.finder.where().findList();
```

And then querying the RegUser.name by:

```
@(regs: List[RegId])

@for(reg <- regs){
    <p>@reg.regUsers.email</p>
}
```

But I can't figure out how to only show distinct records. Is there a way to do this using Ebean or will I need to writ raw sql? I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add a `regIds` field to your RegUsers definition like this:

```
@Entity 
public class RegUsers extends Model{

    public static Finder<Long,RegUsers> find = new Finder<Long,RegUsers>(Long.class, RegUsers.class);

    @Id
    public Long id;

    public String email;
    public String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="regUsers")
    public Set<RegId> regIds;
}
```

you can query for `RegUsers` that have *at least one* `RegId` like this:

```
RegUsers.find.where().isNotNull("regIds.id").findList()
```

if you want to find `RegUsers` with *exactly one* `RegId` then you need to write custom sql indeed.