# play framework: add foreign key to a model '@'?

Tags: playframework, model, foreign-keys

I am trying to add a foreign key to a model, is this possible with the "@" sign....?

So, I have this two models :

```
    @Entity
    public class NewEn extends Model{
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        public int Id;

        public String name;
        public String tags;

        public String user_id;
...
}
```

and:

```
@Entity
public class NewUser extends Model{


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int Id;

    public String username;
    public String first_name;
    public String last_name;
    public String email;
    public String password;

....
}
```

And I want : 'user_id' from the NewEn to be equal with the primary key (Id) from the NewUser model. 
How can I do this in the model, with a @ sign ? Or how can I tie this tables... from my code, not from the database?

Comment: ok, i think i found the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981766/foreign-key-query-play-framework-2-ebean , but i'll appreciate any kind of (other) solution....

Comment: i made the foreign key but my data base doesn't take the users id too :(( ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those words starting with `@` are [annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/). In this case those are [JPA annotations](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence) used to map your objects in Java to your tables/rows in database.

Assuming you are trying to create a 1-N relation between NewUser and NewEn (ie a NewUser object can have many NewEn objects), you need to change it like this:

```
@Entity
public class NewEn extends Model{
    // (...)
    public String tags;

    @ManyToOne
    public NewUser user;
    // (...)
}
```

and then to access the NewUser from a given NewEn you use `someNewEn.user`. If you want to also be able to get all the NewEn objects associated with a given NewUser you specify that in your class file:

```
@Entity
public class NewUser extends Model{

    // (...)
    public String password;

    // mappedBy is the name of the field in NewEn that contains the foreign key
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    public List<NewEn> newEns;
    // (...)
}
```

Note that now, if you want to associate a NewEn to a NewUser you will have to use objects and not simple ids. If you need to work with ids only you will have to do something like this:

```
int userId = 345;
User user = new User();
user.id = userId;

someNewEnObject.user = user;
someNewEnObject.save();
```